# how to send request using xmlhttp to https server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to send a GET request to an HTTPS server using xmlhttp. i am trying the following code:

```
            var getUrl = "https://example.com";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET",getUrl, false);
            xhr.send();
```

the request does not reach the server and i am unable to get a response. what may be the issue?

EDIT: basically my javascript code is in a phonegap application, which has a Same-Origin-Policy.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375908/ajax-get-request-over-https

Comment: maybe duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: i tried sending request to http://google.com and then also, i was unable to send across the request

Comment: Please follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138000/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-work-over-https-on-firefox